# Can you push application user (keychain) data to iOS?

Tags: ios, single-sign-on, enterprise, mdm

We have existing application settings including secured credential data (passwords, names, certificates etc.) which we would like shared to multiple applications (not written by us) running on iOS, rather than requiring the user to re enter the information.  In some cases the users don't have access to password to re enter them manually.

Still learning about possible iOS technologies trying to find something that would support provisioning of this application data.  The MDM seems to be the closest so far, however to my knowledge credentials are limited to general certificates, and application section is limited to the app only.  It would also be nice to be able to do the same for websites accessed in Safari (or others?) without having to introduce a secondary launcher app of our own.

Is MDM the right place for this?  Is there a doc link I've missed?
If not is there some other iOS feature for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

For websites, you could push a webclip with some form of credential in the URL possibly but this would entirely depend on the architecture of the web site you are looking to access. As for pushing items to the keychain, it's not currently possible to do that with MDM.

Answer (score 0):

For provisioning data, you could use APNS notifications instead of MDM (with relies on APNS too).
For sharing data amongst applications, you should consider shared keychain (providing by signing app with the same certificate and add entitlements).

Comment: An interesting idea, this only addresses a trigger really.  Using a shared keychain is not possible to my knowledge - would you sign your app with my key? How about any other app on the store?  The data push has to be able to work to any app on the device regardless of signing or which vendor.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 7 allows you to push data to applications throught MDM.

You can find additional info in WWDC 2013 videoes.